# Issues starting a rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

I am working on an application that makes use of Ruby on Rails. There are 5 of us in the group and so we are using GitHub. I have rails setup on my computer and am able to create my own projects and databases from scratch but when I clone our existing project from GitHub and try to start the server I run into all sorts of issues.

I should mention that I am working on a Windows 7 machine and the initial project was created on a Linux machine. I imagine this could be the source of some of the issues.

Bottom line, when I am in the necessary folder and I type `rails s` I get a lengthy error message that starts with:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32
/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

There is a ton more information that I could provide but I'm not sure what all is needed to help solve this issue. I am a beginner (both with StackOverflow and RoR) so I apologize for not being more clear and concise.

Thanks in advance.

Additional Information:

- mysql: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Win 64 (x86)
- ruby:  Ver 1.9.3p125
- rails: Ver 3.2.0
- mysql gem: Ver 2.9.1
- mysql2 gem: Ver 0.3.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your rails app is trying to log into MySQL with the wrong credentials.

Update the file config/databases.yml to set the rights credentials.

Note that this file should not be checked into version control since it is different for each member of the team.

Comment: Can you help me understand what part of the file I need to change? I'm guessing `database`, `username` and `password` need to be changed, is that correct?

Comment: Have a look at the guides here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database But yes, you have to change the username and password mostly.